# SQL connection issue from paticular folder

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, folder-permissions

Background:

- C# .NET app created that connects to SQL db and does various things
- App uses a fixed SQL id user and password
- App uses a standard connection string:

  - `SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn_string)`
- SQL Server 2008 R2/Windows 7/C#, the shares are in a different domain

Situation:

- User able run the exe and connect to sql from folder1 (\server1\share1\folder1)
- User able run the exe but UNABLE to connect to sql from folder2(\server1\share2\folder2) (receives error 26)
- Drives are on same server however I only have full access at folder1/2 level so unable to view higher up permission's
- I have created a separate folder in folder2 and granted user full control of the folder, user still unable to connect to SQL
- User is able to ping and tracert (created an app and ran from each folder) to server from both drives (assume this shouldn't matter as if client can connect that should be sufficient as exe runs on client?)
- I have tried granting the user and the windows id full sa rights with the same result as a last ditch attempt
- Runs fine from user's local machine
- I am able to run fine and connect from both locations

Summary:

exe can be accessed and run but SQL connection from folder 2 fails for certain users. Users can see server and access fine from a different folder, I believe this is related to some sort of folder permission higher up. What permission on share2 could cause this behavior, and why would it take precedent over the full access I granted on the new child folder?

Comment: is there a reason why you are not having the sql connection string(s) stored in the `App.config || Web.Config` have you tried doing that also do you have code that you can show how you are setting / accessing the connectionStrings from within your code..?

Comment: hi - thanks for response, I've created specific connection/ping/tracert  app to test this issue with a fixed user name and password - initial app used app config with same result; code as requested  - although remember this works from another folder so don't think connection is at fault:

Comment: using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Connstring))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            connection.Open();
                            ConResult = "true";
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex) 
                        {
                            ConResult = ex.ToString();
                        }
                    }

Answer (score 0):

Ok - so I managed to create a solution, now I need to understand the reasoning.

Seems that by adding list,read attrib & read permission at the share2 rectifies the issue.

so to clarify:
-user can traverse from nas server root to the app - connection to sql works fine
-user can't traverse from nas server root but can map the folder where app sits and can access&run app - connection doesn't work

Unsure why any of these folder permissions would affect the connection to sql as effectively the app executes on the client - but that will be my next question....